# Enable both Stateless Spring JWT Authentication and OAuth2 ODIC Based Authentication on jhipster

Tags: spring-security, jhipster, spring-security-oauth2

our existing application Based on Jhipster uses JWT Authentication. We are  using angular + spring boot + postgresql database .
We want to add a feature SSO via openid connect .
Our clients need to access our application via both JWT Auth(email , password,database) and Openid connect (okta, azure).
I tried a lot of examples , but wasn't able to achieve an openid connect  implementation  in our existing application (along with JWT Authentication).
kindly suggest me , what are ways to achieve OAuth implementation in our existing application

Comment: Please share what have you tried and what issues you had. Maybe I am missing something but its unclear to me whether you want to integrate with existing OpenID provider or create be your own provider. Improving formatting would make reading the question easier.